# PDF notes in Preview to EPUB?

Tags: pdf, preview, data-transfer, epub, highlights

I have been making PDF notes in Preview and want to transfer them to EPUB version of the book. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it possible with for example with http://www.wondershare.com/pdf-converter/mac/

Comment: You could also try calibre - free but maybe a bit technical https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30657/

Comment: @amergin I’ve tried Calibre but there is no option to _retain_ the notes (highlighted text made in Preview) when converting to EPUB — They’re all gone after conversion.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It doesn’t do the job — the notes all gone after conversion.

Comment: Maybe do a print to pdf from preview then convert the resulting pdf. Not sure how often you'll be doing this and if it's worth the palaver.